# Compare object in custom list and return the unmatched object C#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have two models

```
public class NewrecordModel
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }
    public string NewFileName { get; set; }
    public string NewFileVersion { get; set; }
}

public class OldrecordModel
{
    public string OldName { get; set; }
    public string OldFileName { get; set; }
    public string OldFileVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I need to compare the property, `NewName` with `OldName` and `NewFileVersion` with `OldFileVersion` and return the difference from `NewrecordModel` in a list.

I tried the below one,

```
var unMatchedRecord = NewrecordModel.Where(o => !OldrecordModel.Any(n => n.OldName == o.NewName) || !OldrecordModel.Any(n => n.OldFileVersion == o.NewFileVersion));
```

The above one is returning the unmatch `NewrecordModel` in a list and it is working fine, but i need to compare OldFileVersion  is less than NewFileVersion and return the list now. While using `OldFileVersion`  is less than `NewFileVersion` in query it is listing unrelated data as output.

Below is the query i tried to compare,

```
var unMatchedVersion = NewrecordModel.Where(o => OldrecordModel.Any(n => n.OldFileVersion.ToInt() < o.NewFileVersion.ToInt()));
```

Is the above linq is correct. How to compare the numbers in linq and return the result.

Comment: It seems unclear what is your definition of "unmatched object". It might be an object from NewrecordModel collection, for which there are no objects in OldrecordModel collection with the same name OR any identically named object from OldrecordModel collection has a smaller OldFileVersion. Or it might be an object from NewrecordModel collection, for which there are no objects in OldrecordModel collection with the same name AND all the objects in OldrecordModel  collection have smaller values of their OldFileVersion property. Which one do you need?

Comment: @rs232 i need the first one that is "It might be an object from NewrecordModel collection, for which there are no objects in OldrecordModel collection with the same name OR any identically named object from OldrecordModel collection has a smaller OldFileVersion"

Comment: Then we can rephrase this definition as "an object from NewrecordModel Where Any object from OldrecordModel has a different name or has its OldFileVersion less then the newrecordmodelobject's NewFileVersion". Which is basically a LINQ clause written in English.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for get properties name and value what changed. I hope this help you.

```
public static class CompareObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compares the properties of two objects of the same type and returns if all properties are equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objectA">The first object to compare.</param>
        /// <param name="objectB">The second object to compre.</param>
        /// <param name="ignoreList">A list of property names to ignore from the comparison.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if all property values are equal, otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
        public static Dictionary<string,object> AreObjectsEqual(object objectA, object objectB, params string[] ignoreList)
        {
            //bool result;
            var list = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (objectA != null && objectB != null)
            {
                Type objectType;

                objectType = objectA.GetType();

                //result = true; // assume by default they are equal

                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.CanRead && !ignoreList.Contains(p.Name)))
                {


                    // if it is a primative type, value type or implements IComparable, just directly try and compare the value
                    if (CanDirectlyCompare(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                    {
                        object valueA;
                        object valueB;

                        valueA = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectA, null);
                        valueB = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectB, null);
                        if (!AreValuesEqual(valueA, valueB))
                        {
                            list.Add(propertyInfo.Name, valueA);
                            //Console.WriteLine("Mismatch with property '{0}.{1}' found.", objectType.FullName, propertyInfo.Name);
                            //result = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //else
            //    result = object.Equals(objectA, objectB);

            return list;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether value instances of the specified type can be directly compared.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if this value instances of the specified type can be directly compared; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool CanDirectlyCompare(Type type)
        {
            return typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(type) || type.IsPrimitive || type.IsValueType;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares two values and returns if they are the same.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="valueA">The first value to compare.</param>
        /// <param name="valueB">The second value to compare.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if both values match, otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
        private static bool AreValuesEqual(object valueA, object valueB)
        {
            bool result;
            IComparable selfValueComparer;

            selfValueComparer = valueA as IComparable;

            if (valueA == null && valueB != null || valueA != null && valueB == null)
                result = false; // one of the values is null
            else if (selfValueComparer != null && selfValueComparer.CompareTo(valueB) != 0)
                result = false; // the comparison using IComparable failed
            else if (!object.Equals(valueA, valueB))
                result = false; // the comparison using Equals failed
            else
                result = true; // match

            return result;
        }

    }
```

and to use

```
var changedColumns = CompareObject.AreObjectsEqual(NewrecordModel, OldrecordModel);
```

Comment: This looks like a terrible overkill and a really bad design.

Comment: If you ever add/remove properties to/from NewrecordModel or OldrecordModel classes, you need to go through all the places where your piece of code is used and change them, which is error-prone and not even always possible.

Comment: @rs232 Why? do you better idea?

Comment: I have added a comment explaining why it is a bad design. I believe that it is pretty obvious why it is an overkill.

Comment: Your solution is to compare the objects of the same classes while OP has slightly different problem. He has separate classes to compare.

Answer (score 0):

> It might be an object from NewrecordModel collection, for which there are no objects in OldrecordModel collection with the same name OR any identically named object from OldrecordModel collection has a smaller OldFileVersion

Check the codes below:

```
    var unMatchedVersion = 
        newrecordModel.Where(o => !oldrecordModel.Any(n => n.OldName == o.NewName) ||
        oldrecordModel.Any(n => n.OldName == o.NewName && 
        int.Parse(n.OldFileVersion) < int.Parse(o.NewFileVersion)));
```

Comment: You really don't need two oldrecordModel.Any checks. The object qualifies either if it has a different name OR if its fileVersion is smaller.

Comment: @rs232 Perhaps you right, but why don't you write your own answer?

Comment: Because I believe that SO should not be a code-writing service. It is always a good idea to help someone to understand something they are missing. It is a bad idea to just write code for someone, by doing this you: a) do not give them a chance to learn new things, b) encourage "write code for me" behaviour, c) decrease the overall quality of SO.

Comment: You describe SO as "Question and comment" instead of  "Question and Answer" site.

Comment: When the question is trivial (like this one) then it definitely does not deserve any answer, giving a hint in comments is quite enough. Unless you are hungry for scores, badges and other bright shiny trinkets, of course.